# Annotating Pandas DataFrame with Bin Information based on DateTime (Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Annually)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, binning

As mentioned in the subject, I'm hoping to annotate a Pandas DataFrame by adding a column, calculated from another column already formatted as a Pandas DateTime object, referencing a 'bin' that DateTime falls in. At first I had attempted to use Pandas.date_range() and the resulting DateTimeIndex to perform this calculation, but it appears that the DateTimeIndex is poorly situated for such a calculation. I have described below my attempt and what I had hoped for, but trolling through the Pandas documentation has not revealed an elegant way to achieve the result I'm looking for, any advice would be appreciated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['Jeffrey', 'Melinda', 'Niall', 'Chris', 'Sally', 'Jeff'], 'DOB':['03/04/2001', '06/04/2001', '07/04/2001', '04/26/1999', '04/04/2001', '12/12/2000']}) 

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])

start = min(df['DOB'])
end = max(df['DOB'])

dr = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='Q')

# This is where I get stuck, I effectively would want to be able to take any given date from
# 'df['DOB']' and know which index in the DateTimeIndex object it should fall under. 
# For example, the date '07/04/2001' should fall in the '2001-06-30' index of the above date range
```

This question feels like there should be an easy, elegant solution, but everything I've seen is a little more involved. Thanks for any advice!

Ideally the end result would look as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['Jeffrey', 'Melinda', 'Niall', 'Chris', 'Sally', 'Jeff'], 'DOB':['03/04/2001', '06/04/2001', '07/04/2001', '04/26/1999', '04/04/2001', '12/12/2000'], 'Bin': [7, 8, 9, 0, 8, 6]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I was having a moment and looking in the completely wrong place, what I wanted to achieve above can be done in a single line using the following code:

```
df['Bin'] = df['DOB'].dt.to_period('Q')
```

This output isn't outputting an integer bin as I had stated above, but I imagine the conversion wouldn't be all that difficult and the above solution works fine for my application.

Hopefully my confusion might help someone else!